# Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 10, column: 3, Unexpected data after root element

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm learning about developing Google Chrome extensions.  Upon attempting to load my extension, I receive the following message:

`Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 10, column: 3, Unexpected data after root element.`

Below is my manifest.json file:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "ShowTime",
  "description": "Extension to show the current date and time",
  "version": "1.2",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "A plain text description",
  "icons": {
     "16": "icon16.png",
     "48": "icon48.png",
     "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
     "default_title": "ShowTime",
     "default_icon": "icon.png", 
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: I saw that I had a duplicate description field. Here is the updated manifest.json, but i still get "Unexpected data after root element" error.

{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "ShowTime",
  "description": "Extension to show the current date and time",
  "version": "1.2",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "icons": { "16": "icon16.png", "48": "icon48.png", "128": "icon128.png" },
  "browser_action": { "default_title": "ShowTime", "default_icon": "icon.png", "default_popup": "popup.html" }
}

Comment: Hope this helps someone...

{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "ShowTime",
  "description": "Extension to show the current date and time",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "ShowTime",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "icons": { 
     "16": "icon16.png", 
     "48": "icon48.png", 
     "128": "icon128.png" 
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}